# python - Pattern matching assign regex groups to class members

Tags: python, regex, variable-assignment

I am trying to parse a data stream into a class by defining a regex with named groups that correspond to the member variables.

---

```
import re  
##-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
pattern = """^(?P<A>\w{4})(?P<B>\w{4})(?P<C>\w{4})"""  
##-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
class Data:  
    def __init__(self):  
       self.A       = 0     ##4 bytes  
       self.B       = 0     ##4 bytes  
       self.C       = 0     ##4 bytes  

    def show(self):  
       print( "Data:" )  
       print( "------------------------------------" )  
       members = [attr for attr in dir(self) if not callable(getattr(self,attr)) and not attr.startswith("__")]  
       for member in members:  
           print("%s:%s" % (member, getattr(self, member)) )  
##-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
hex_stream = "00001111BEEF"  
##-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SearchObj = re.search(pattern, hex_stream, re.I)  
if SearchObj:  
    D = Data()  
    members = [attr for attr in dir(D) if not callable(getattr(D, attr)) and not attr.startswith("__")]  
    for member in members:  
        grp_name = "\'"  +member + "\'"  
        print( grp_name )  
        setattr( D, member, int( SearchObj.group( grp_name ), 16 ) )  
        val = getattr( D, member )  
        print("%s:%s" % ( val, member ) )
```

---

The above complains about there being "no such group" on the setattr() line when 'A' is printed for the grp_name.  Where syntactically am I going wrong?

Comment: Why do you add `'`s to member? The group name is `A`, not `'A'`.

Comment: It appears I had made some other error previously when I did not have the single quotes, and added them in attempt to fix the problem.  Removing the quote addition seems to fix the issue.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'd change the **init** method to take the member values, like so:

```
class Data:  
    def __init__(self, A, B, C):  
       self.A       = A
       self.B       = B  
       self.C       = C
```

Then, you can use the match.groupdict method like so:

```
match = re.search(pattern, hex_stream, re.I) 
if match:
    # pmatch is a dict (grp_name -> grp_value)
    pmatch = match.groupdict()
    # we create a new dict by converting the grp_value to an int:
    params={name: int(value,16) for (name,value) in pmatch.items()}
    # then we just create D from those values.
    D = Data(**params)
```

So why should you do it that way?

The implementation you posted inspects the object D in order to determine the attributes that need to be set.  What happens if you add a non-callable member to your class later on?  It will get very messy.  It's also difficult to understand.  Since your regex match tells you which attributes it knows, you should only set those.

Answer (score 0):

You loop over the groups using `for member in members:`, which means that in every iteration, `member` contains the group name.

You then make `grp_name` from `member` by embedding it in `'`'s, which is the problem. Instead of  `grp_name` being the group name `A`, it's `'A'`, which is not an existing group name. Not adding the `'`s will fix the problem.